# How to filter columns in place in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for the opposite of  `df.drop(columns, inplace=True)` . That is, I have a list of columns to keep, and need the rest of the columns to be dropped in place. I've tried the following:

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(np.array(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])),columns=['one', 'two', 'three']),
       pd.DataFrame(np.array(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])),columns=['one', 'two', 'four'])]

s = list(set(dfs[0].columns).intersection(*[x.columns for x in dfs[1:]]))
print(s)
for df in dfs:
    df = df.filter(s, axis=1)
print([df.shape for df in dfs])
```

Which prints

```
>> ['one', 'two']
>> [(2, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Whereas I want

```
>> ['one', 'two']
>> [(2, 2), (2, 2)]
```

I understand why this code fails, but don't have an "in place" option that works.

Comment: @anky_91 yes that works, but is there any way the operation can be performed in place?

Comment: @anky_91 extracting in place - or in other words, dropping the columns not in the list in place. Really, I want the exact functionality of `.filter` if that function included the `inplace` argument that `drop` includes.

Comment: @anky_91 If you make that an answer, I'll probably accept it, I didn't know about the `columns.difference()` function either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming column names are unique you could do:

```
all = set(df.columns.tolist())
to_drop = list(all - set(s))
df.drop(columns=to_drop, inplace=True)
```

**EDIT:** you can also use [`pd.Index.difference()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) and `drop` with it:

```
df.drop(df.columns.difference(list_of_col),inplace=True)
```